# It's possible to have fixed properties in object with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, typeguards

Using spread operators, properties are widened so bug traces become hard. Can I prevent from properties widening?

```
type Fields = {prop1:string; prop2:number};

// Here, it's no problem. I can't add any properties other than those declared in type Fields.
const a:Fields = {prop1:'1', prop2:2, prop3:'3'}; // This causes type error, good job!

// But here, when using spread operators, I can add any properties unless losing those in Feilds.
const b:Fields = {...a, ...{prop3:'3'}}; // No error...
```

Comment: Issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39998). A more explicit duplicate can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41698).